# Setting the textbox value once permanently in visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am new to the C# programming. I am using winforms and I am making an small application where I have to send mails to 10-15 mail id. For this, first I need to enter the mail id in the text box and then send mail. If I have to send mail again, the mail ids entered earlier should appear in the text boxes so that I can just click send mail button. If I need to edit any mail id, I'll edit it and from the next time, new updated mail id should appear in the text box.

How to do that. Do I need any database for this. I don't have any experience in creating databases.Please help me with the simple solution. Any reference or link from where I can learn.

Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't need to be persistent, you can store the mail IDs in a `List<string>` and just append/edit to this `List`. If it needs to be persistent (for example, you need the mail IDs when the application restarts), you will need to write this data somewhere. A database would be a little overkill, but a flat file will do you. Something as simple as a CSV would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to keep the email ID you entered once throughout your application life cycle or even after the restarting the application?

1. If you need the text box value throughout the application alone, then you could use the textbox.Text property, maybe assign it to some member throughout the application and get it whenever required.
2. If your requirement is such that the data needs to be kept even if the application is restarted, you may need to store the entered value in a database. But using a database for just this purpose may not be efficient. You may consider using a text file or xml file for this scenario.

You could easily find in google how to achieve the things mentioned above and get lots of samples for the same.

**See the code below for xml serialization/deserialization.**

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializes an object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
            stream.Position = 0;
            xmlDocument.Load(stream);
            xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

    T objectOut = default(T);

    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
        string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

        using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            Type outType = typeof(T);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
            {
                objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }

            read.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }

    return objectOut;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my requirement is the one which you have mentioned in your second point. Is is possible I can get those email ids from a text file and it automatically shows in textbox. I will definitely search about it.

Comment: @annacarolina You'll have to read the text file then append the items (the text file's contents) to the `TextBox`. Perhaps a `ListBox` would be a better control to manage this?

Comment: Welcome. I have added some sample code in my answer. Please check.

Comment: You could also consider using **StringWriter** and **StringReader** for writing/reading from a text file. But **xml** is more preferred nowadays. You could also consider writing data to db, if the requirement of data storage is high, such as you need to store 1000's of email ID's. Please learn about xml serialization too.

Comment: Thanks I have finally extracted the data by reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the demo code which I have used. I have used a button to read file and then using splitter to split the text and display it in text box.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream file;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((file = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {

                string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
                string fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);


                string[] newText = fileText.Split('Q');

                st1name.Text = newText[0];
                st1email.Text = newText[1];
                st2name.Text = newText[2];
                st2email.Text = newText[3];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. It will be definitely useful for someone who is facing similar kind of issue.